# React Native's ScrollView Broken on iOS Physical Device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, reactjs, react-native

I have an issue on React Native's iOS ScrollView, it was broken after implementing GIF's while scrolling. It happened only on physical device, not on Simulator (works fine). Xcode log said it was caused by a memory issue problem.

React version: 16.0.0-alpha.12,
RN version: 0.48.3

Comment: If its possible you could try to download smaller images (just in case you didn't look for the size of them yet). Had the same issue cause by downloading lots of high res images, wich are not needed for mobile devices.

Comment: @jonathan-stellwag I think it was happened because of my GIFs image because if I don't include its, the app was fine. Is there another way to put the GIFs on my iOS RN app?

Comment: I found a closed issue at github wich handles also a memory issue in relation to GIF's on iOS. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9662
If this solves your issue I write an answer for this

Comment: @jonathan-stellwag Yes, it does. Thank you, man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is a known issue in Github about using GIF images on iOS:**

[Terminated due to memory issue on ios](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9662)

**If you follow the comments you someone made a solution for this issue by providing a package for those Images:**

[react-native-flanimatedimage](https://github.com/nihgwu/react-native-flanimatedimage)

*Seems like the commend among the main question was the solution, so i set it available for all wich are interested in*